# ¿Como hacer una consulta donde se muestren todos los datos de una tabla mas los datos de otra tabla donde tiene una condición?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Tengo dos tablas, una llamada vacantes otra llamada postulaciones.

La tabla vacantes esta estructurada de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla postulaciones se llena cuando un usuario le interesa un aviso en pantalla y su estructura es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero realizar es una consulta donde muestre todos los registros de la tabla vacantes y los registros de un usuario especifico.

Lo que tengo por ahora es una consulta con un left join, pero me muestra solamente los registros que coinciden con la tabla vacantes y no trae todos los datos.
Esta es mi consulta:

```html
SELECT vacantes.*, postulaciones.Id_vacante, postulaciones.id_usu AS postulado  
FROM vacantes  
LEFT JOIN postulaciones ON postulaciones. id_vacante = vacantes.id_vacante 
WHERE postulaciones.id_usu = 1 order by fecha_captura desc
```

¿Alguna idea de como realizar esta consulta correctamente?

Mi tabla vacantes tiene los siguientes registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi tabla postulaciones tiene los siguientes registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces al hacer la consulta que puse el resultado es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como notaran hay 3 resgistros por que el usuario 1 de la tabla postulaciones contiene esos 3 id de la tabla vacantes.

Lo que quiero es que me muestre esos 3 mas la vacante que falta que es el id 7 de la tabla vacantes.

El resultado seria algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Amigo, explícame nuevamente que es el resultado que quieres obtener de la consulta, es que no entiendo, lo que entiendo es que quieres todos los registros de las vacantes y aparte el registro de un usuario en específico

Comment: @Osaskoh Que tal Amigo, gracias por comentar. Edite la pregunto, viene mis datos y  el resultado que quiero obtener. Me podrías apoyar por favor. Espero sea entendible

Answer (score 0):

Quítale el `WHERE`:

```sql
SELECT vacantes.*, postulaciones.Id_vacante, postulaciones.id_usu AS postulado  
FROM vacantes  
LEFT JOIN postulaciones ON postulaciones. id_vacante = vacantes.id_vacante
```

Comment: Entiendo perfectamente tu respuesta, es una excelente solución. Solo tengo una duda, la query que puse es con la condición where por que el usuario entra con su sesión, entonces si lo pongo como tu respuesta en si serian los mismos datos para todos, no? o eso ya lo tengo que validar desde programación?

Comment: Pefecto amigo, de igual forma me funciono, lo valide desde el código de progracion.

Comment: @LuisAlberto, si te fue útil, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta, o redacta una respuesta propia explicando cómo resolviste tu problema, y acéptala.

Answer (score 0):

Hermano un gusto poderte ayudar, espero lo que te escribo sea lo que necesitas.
para esto tengo 2 tablas con estos registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ejecuté estos queries:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y bueno, verás que el ejemplo es igual que tu caso, tengo muchas pages y en los permisos no tengo incluidas todas esas pages por tanto con el siguiente query saco lo que tu quieres:

```
select p.* , per.* from pages p left join permisos per on p.ID = per.id_page
```

y obtengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces siguiendo mi lógica en tu caso sería:

```
   select v.*,p.* 
from vacantes v left join postulaciones p
 on v.id_vacante = p.id_vacante
```

Comment: Entiendo perfectamente tu respuesta Amigo,, es una excelente solución. Solo tengo una duda, la query que puse es con la condición where por que el usuario entra con su sesión, entonces si lo pongo como tu respuesta en si serian los mismos datos para todos, no? o eso ya lo tengo que validar desde programación?

Comment: si lo que quieres es que cada usuario que entre pueda ver las vacantes enteras y las que él a aplicado entonces si, tienes que meter un where en la query donde pongas id_usuario= [valor] claro.

Comment: Utilice la consulta que me proporcionaste y despues compare si el id_usu de la consulta es igual al usuario logueado entonces ya obtengo el resultado. Al parecer esta funcionando

Comment: excelente :) que bueno que pude ayudar

Comment: Y en todo caso, si no quisiera validarlo por el codigo, entonces... como seria ? desde la consulta?

Comment: Tienes que validarlo por código, por que es la única manera de saber que usuario es el logeado, piensalo, no hay forma de que SQL sepa que usuario debe filtrar si no es por que tú se lo mandaste en la query por tu código